# Ubuntu 18.04 : firefox unable to connect to mobile hotspot but USB tethering and other wireless connections work fine

Tags: networking, 18.04, firefox, internet, hot-spot

I have a very strange problem, which I must say, I haven't faced before.

Recently I upgraded my system from 16.04 to 18.04 in my HP laptop. I generally access internet via wireless connection. Most of the time I share my mobile internet connection with my laptop by creating a mobile-hotspot. As you know it is also possible to share the connection via USB tethering. In 16.04 I did not have any problem. In fact, I upgraded to 18.04 by sharing my mobile internet with my laptop via mobile-hotspot.

But after upgrading to 18.04, what I find is that Firefox cannot connect to the internet via the mobile-hotspot created by mobile. Surprisingly, Firefox works while I am sharing my mobile internet via USB tethering and also other available wireless connection. My laptop shows that it is connected to the mobile-hotspot. In connection information I get some automatic IP and DNS addresses. I can ping to those automatic IP and DNS addresses. But still Firefox or other browser (I have Chromium) won't connect to the internet when I use my mobile-hotspot.

Any idea to solve it?

Output of ifconfig:

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1821  bytes 145195 (145.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1821  bytes 145195 (145.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlo1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.83  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::97a1:23f9:42a6:52a1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 30:e3:7a:ce:28:ef  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11445  bytes 10243390 (10.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9937  bytes 1278923 (1.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have some doubt. I use two different wireless connection in my laptop. For office/home wireless I use static ip with `netmask 255.255.255.0`. For mobile-hotspot I use automatic DHCP and nothing is set by hand. Why the netmask is same ? Sorry, it may be a dumb question.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Is this a hotspot you created in Ubuntu via tethering to your phone? Sorry, I'm unclear on what you are saying. Please [edit] your post to provide clarity. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Dear @Elder Geek, I have edited my post as you suggested. I hope, this time it is more clear. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `netstat -ie` or `ifconfig` when your laptop "shows that it is connected to the mobile-hotspot." Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @Elder Geek : I have added the output. Please take a look. Thank you a lot for trying to help me.

Comment: I'm always willing to try. Please also [edit] the output of `ip r` into your post when your laptop "shows that it is connected to the mobile-hotspot." Thank you for helping us help you!